# Cannot create database with SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy

I am trying to run my create_db.py file to create the posts.db database, but it will not get created in my project directory. And when I run the main file for the blog and try to login in I get the error below.

I have looked up this error and seen that other people have gotten it as well and asked about it here on Stackoverflow, but none of them seems to help me. I have read that this could be because something in my blog.py file is running **main** before the database gets created. But, I am thinking that it has something to do with the configuration. Mainly the PATH of the database could be getting mixed up with the `app.config['SQLAlCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///'` line.

Any ideas?

**Here is the error**

sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError

OperationalError: (OperationalError) no such table: posts u'SELECT posts.id AS posts_id, posts.title AS posts_title, posts.post AS posts_post \nFROM posts' ()

OperationalError: (OperationalError) no such table: posts u'SELECT posts.id AS posts_id, posts.title AS posts_title, posts.post AS posts_post \nFROM posts' ()

Here is my code. There are three files here: blog.py, models.py, create_db.py

**blog.py**
    # controller of blog app

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, session,\
    flash, redirect, url_for, g
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import sqlite3
from functools import wraps


# create the application object
app = Flask(__name__)

# configuration
app.secret_key = 'x13xa8xf5}[xfexd4Zxb8+x07=7xc9xe1Bxcfxbdt.ox87oxc9'
app.config['SQLAlCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///'

# create sqlalchemy object

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

from models import *

# login required decorator
def login_required(test):
    @wraps(test)
    def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
        if 'logged_in' in session:
            return test(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            flash('You need to login first.')
            return redirect(url_for('login'))
    return wrap

@app.route('/', methods = ['GET','POST'])
def login():
    error = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.form['username'] != 'admin' or request.form['password'] != 'admin':
            error = 'Invalid Credentils. Please try again.'
        else:
            session['logged_in'] = True
            return redirect(url_for('main'))
    return render_template('login.html', error=error)

@app.route('/main')
@login_required
def main():
    posts = db.session.query(BlogPost).all()
    return render_template('main.html', posts=posts)

@app.route('/add', methods=['POST'])
@login_required
def add():
    title = request.form['title']
    post = request.form['post']
    if not title or not post:
        flash("All fields are required. Please try again.")
        return redirect(url_for('main'))
    else:
        db.session.add(title)
        db.session.add(post)
        db.session.commit()
        db.session.close()
        flash('New entry was successfully posted!')
        return redirect(url_for('main'))


@app.route('/logout')
def logout():
    session.pop('logged_in', None)
    flash('You were logged out')
    return redirect(url_for('login'))

def connect_db():
    return sqlite.connect('posts.db')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug = True)
```

**models.py:**

```
from blog import db

class BlogPost(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = "posts"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    post = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)

    def __init__(self, title, post):
        self.title = title
        self.post = post

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<title {}'.format(self.title)
```

**create_db.py**

```
from blog import db
from models import BlogPost

# create the database and the db tables
db.create_all()

# insert
db.session.add(BlogPost("Good","I\'m good."))
db.session.add(BlogPost("Well","I\'m well."))
db.session.add(BlogPost("Post","I\'m a post."))

# commit the changes

db.session.commit()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a typo in `SQLAlCHEMY_DATABASE_URI`, should be `SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI`, the 2nd `l`.

When running `from blog import db` some statements in `blog.py` get executed, including the one with `sqlite:///` which is where the path is set. Modifying this line

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///posts.db'
```

and then after running `create_db.py` should create a database in app's root directory. There doesn't seem to be another place in the code where the db path is set.

It looks like you may also run into some circular import problems (will throw `ImportError: cannot import name [name]`). Some solutions are putting the app init stuff like `db = SQLAlchemy..` into a separate file or importing at the end of the file.

Comment: Than you, that worked. I did not run into any circular import problems. But, I did find that my code for adding new blog posts was wrong. But it was an easy fix. *db.session.add(BlogPost(title, post))* instead of *db.session.add(title, post)*

Comment: Thanks, it works for me too.